# Using fold_left to search for a list with a specific length in OCaml

Tags: list, search, ocaml, fold

I've written a function which search through a list of int-list to return the index of the list with an specific length by using pattern-matching:

```
    let rec search x lst i = match lst with
   | [] -> raise(Failure "Not found")
   | hd :: tl -> if (List.length hd = x) then i else search x tl (i+1)
    ;;
```

For example:

```
utop # search 2 [ [1;2];[1;2;3] ] 0 ;;
- : int = 0
```

Is there a way to write a function with the same functionality using `fold.left` ?

Comment: Yes there is, but folds really aren't a good fit for traversals that terminate early. More generally for these kinds of basic questions, though: Have you tried yourself? Did you encounter any problem with it?

Comment: `failwith "Not found"` instead of `raise(Failure "Not found")`, btw.

Comment: Even better: `raise Not_found` (the stdlib has such an exception for that kind of situations).

Answer (score 2):

What does `List.fold_left` actually do?

It takes (in reverse order to the order of arguments) a list, an initial value, and a function that works on that initial value and the first element in the list. If the list is empty, it returns the initial value. Otherwise it uses the function to update the initial value by way of recursion and works on the tail of the list.

```
let rec fold_left f init lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> init
  | x::xs -> fold_left f (f init x) xs
```

Now, what information do you need to keep track of as you iterate? The index. Easy enough.

But, what if you don't actually find a list of that length? You need to keep track of whether you've found one. So let's say we use a tuple of the index and a boolean flag.

Your function you pass to `fold_left` just needs to determine *if* a match has been found no update is necessary. Essentially we just no-op over the rest of the list. But, if we haven't found a match, then we need to test the current sublist's length and update the init value accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

@glennsl (in a comment) and @Chris already explained that you *may* use `List.fold_left` but that it’s not the right tool for the job, because it processes the whole list whereas you want to stop once an occurrence is found. There are solutions but they are not satisfying:

- (@Chris’ solution:) use a folding function that ignores the new elements once an occurrence has been found: you’re just wasting time, walking through the remaining tail for nothing;
- evade the loop by throwing and catching an exception: better but hacky, you’re working around the normal functioning of `List.fold_left`.

I just mention that there *is* a generic function in [the standard library](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html) that matches your situation almost perfectly:

```ml
val find : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a
```

> `find f l` returns the first element of the list `l` that satisfies the predicate `f`.
> Raises `Not_found` if there is no value that satisfies `f` in the list `l`.

However it does not return the index, unlike what you are asking for. This is a deliberate design choice in the standard library, because list indexing is inefficient (linear time) and you shouldn’t do it. If, after these cautionary words, you still want the index, it is easy to write a generic function `find_with_index`.

---

Another remark on your code: you can avoid computing the lengths of inner lists fully, thanks to the following standard function:

```ml
val compare_length_with : 'a list -> int -> int
```

> Compare the length of a list to an integer. `compare_length_with l len` is equivalent to `compare (length l) len`, except that the computation stops after at most `len` iterations on the list.
> Since 4.05.0

So instead of  `if List.length hd = x`, you can do `if List.compare_length_with hd x = 0`.